# Get recipient to pay transaction fee when transferring SPL token

Tags: fees

Is it possible to have recipient to pay transaction fee when transferring SPL token?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the recipient would have to become the fee payer.

This would require having the transaction signed by the sender and by the receiver.

- Sender signs to allow token transfer
- Receiver signs as fee payer

Comment: Sounds to me this involves two steps - sender signs the transaction with keypair and how to request recipient to sign the same transaction instruction. An example of code to archive this is very much appreciated.